# SQL Date to only display the day and not the YYYY MM DD

Tags: sql, date

As you can see, I am returning the full YYYY/MM/DD on my query.  However I only want the display to show the day.

Could anyone assist me in what I should be doing to achieve this?
I can format the date, and set my characters but it still only shows the beginning of the date, for example 2019.

Any idea?

```
USE CBS_AFRICA_LIVECOPY;

SELECT START_LOAD_TIME
FROM ORDERS
WHERE LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = '11011';
```

returns

```
START_LOAD_TIME
---------------
2018-01-31 12:11:44.000
2018-01-31 16:43:56.000
2018-01-31 19:24:58.000
2018-01-31 10:49:10.000
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, have you tried googling it, because it is a pretty simple job, which can be found by direct search

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Show us some sample table data AND the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select Day('your datetime field') as Order_Entry_Time
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.  However I noticed that it replaces the header as a (No Column Name), how do I run the query which will show the original name which should be Order_Entry_Time ?

Comment: @ArriBenson write an explicit alias to the column expression: `select Day('your datetime field')  AS Order_Entry_Time`

Comment: @ArriBenson  I have edited the answer for your requirement, And please mark it as answer if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT function to change the way the select return your data.
This should resolve your problem:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), START_LOAD_TIME, 120)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = '11011';
```

You may consult here the different formats you can use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017